# Trying to add up numbers in PHP for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to add up all numbers that are output in my code, how can I do this?

```
$tall1 = 0;

for ($tall1=0; $tall1 <= 100; $tall1++) { 
    if ($tall1 % 3 == 0) {
        echo $tall1 . " ";
        $tall++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When developing and testing code, at the top of your script use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. You would have seen PHP complain about an undefined variable `$tall`, maybe making your mistake easier to spot.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Of course....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$total = 0; //initialize variable

for ($tall1=0; $tall1 <= 100; $tall1++) { 
    if ($tall1 % 3 == 0) {
        echo $tall1 . " ";
        $total += $tall1; //add the printed number to the previously initialized variable. This is the same as writing $total = $total + $tall1;
    }
}

echo "total: ".$total; //do something with the variable, in this case, print it
```

Some notes about your initial code:

```
$tall1 = 0; //you don't need to do this, it is done by the for loop
for (
     $tall1=0; //this is where $tall1 is initialized
     $tall1 <= 100; 
     $tall1++ //this is where $tall1 is incremented every time
       ) { 
    if ($tall1 % 3 == 0) {
        echo $tall1 . " ";
        $tall++; //this variable is not used anywhere. If you meant $tall1, then you don't need to do this, it is done by the for loop. If you did not mean $tall1, but wanted to count how many times the if statement runs, then you need to initialize this variable (place something like $tall=0; at the top)
    }
}
```